# In sales and trends, why does proceeds divided by sales only = 66% and not 70%?

Tags: app-store-connect

Recently Apple started including "sales" in iTunes Connect Sales and Trends which denotes the total revenue your app has made before Apple takes its 30% cut, while "proceeds" is what you made after the cut is subtracted.

Why is it when I take my lifetime proceeds and divide it by my lifetime sales, I only get 66-67% instead of 70%? What is happening to this other 3-4%?

Comment: Lots of rounding error, maybe? What did Apple say when you asked them?

Comment: @AaronBrager Haven't asked just yet.

Comment: You'd need to ask Apple to be sure. Maybe all sales are included in Lifetime Sales and refunds are deducted from Lifetime Proceeds? Seems really high for refunds though. Is there any currency conversion in play?

Comment: @tubedogg that's exactly what I was thinking. Maybe Apple takes its 30% from the stronger currencies rather than taking 30% from each currency.